# Removal of 2 story chimney with deteriorated bricks

Tags: removal, chimney

The bricks of the chimney are deteriorated beyond repair. it is located on the outside of the house and is a 2 story structure.   The fireplace has been converted to gas logs and the chimney is not used for anything else.   What are the concerns when removing the chimney? We are aware that the roof will need to be repaired. What about the exterior of the house? Can we take the Chimney down ourselves? What else do I need to consider?

Comment: Welcome to DIYSE. Those are some broad and subjective questions, I'm afraid. Whether the exterior needs repair depends on many factors (about which we know nothing), and whether you can do the job depends on your skills, physical condition, and risk tolerance (also about which we know nothing). Please revise to ask something more specific (see the [help pages](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance), or delete and ask later when you have a more specific question.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to ask a specific question, it will almost certainly be useful to include a picture of the chimney.  Do you want to remove the chimney to roof level or ground level?  What is the rest of wall made from?  Do the gas logs need a flue, or are they safe to burn in an enclosed room (read the manual!)